# Function ends before all asynchronous work completes

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

So I have a function that checks if an order is 24 hours old, if thats the case I send a notification to the user , but it seems like it does not complete the execution of all the users, instead it just returns someones and some others not, I think I have a problem returning the promise, I'm not an expert in javascript and I did not really understand what is happening, sometimes instead of trying with all the documents it just finishes if one documents has a deviceToken as empty and not continue with the other user documents

```
exports.rememberToFinishOrder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 3 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    var db = admin.firestore();
    const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis()
    const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) //24 horas
    let snap = await db.collection('orders').where("timestamp","<",new Date(compareDate)).where("status", "in" ,[1,2,4,5,6]).get()
    if(snap.size > 0){
         snap.forEach(async(doc) => {
            const userId = doc.data().uid
            let userSnap = await db.collection('user').doc(userId).get()
                const deviceToken = userSnap.data().deviceToken
                const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "¿ Did you received your order ?",
                    body: "We need to know if you have received your order",
                    clickAction: "AppMainActivity"
                },
                data: {
                    ORDER_REMINDER: "ORDER_REMINDER"
                }
            }
            console.log("User: "+doc.data().uid)
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload) 
        }); 
    } 
});
```

sometimes when in someusers the devicetoken is empty it will finish the execution of this function instead of continuing to the next user, and also it will not finish this function for all the users in my orders collection, it will do someones and someones not, and this should be an atomic operation that changes everything in that collection, not just some documents

what is happening ?

Comment: i gave you the pattern in the other question, you can apply the same here. If you are going to use forEach, you need to use Promise.all to await for all the promises to be resolved, otherwise, you can go with the for-of approach

Comment: is there a consice approach ?

Comment: what do you mean? your error is that you are not handling promises correctly

Comment: can you please help me with this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like andresmijares are saying, are you not handling the promises correctly.
When you are doing several asynchronous calls, I'd suggest using the Promise.all() function that will wait for all the promises to be done before it continues.

```
exports.rememberToFinishOrder = functions.pubsub.schedule('every 3 minutes').onRun(async (context) => {
    const db = admin.firestore();
    const messaging = admin.messaging();

    const tsToMillis = admin.firestore.Timestamp.now().toMillis()
    const compareDate = new Date(tsToMillis - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) //24 horas
    
    const snap = await db.collection('orders').where("timestamp","<",new Date(compareDate)).where("status", "in" ,[1,2,4,5,6]).get()
    let allPromises = [];

    if(snap.size > 0){
        snap.forEach((doc) => {
            const userId = doc.data().uid;

            allPromises.push(db.collection('user').doc(userId).get().then(userSnapshot => {
                const userData = userSnapshot.data();
                const deviceToken = userData.deviceToken;
                if (userData && deviceToken) {
                    
                    const payload = {
                        notification: {
                            title: "¿ Did you received your order ?",
                            body: "We need to know if you have received your order",
                            clickAction: "AppMainActivity"
                        },
                        data: {
                            ORDER_REMINDER: "ORDER_REMINDER"
                        }
                    }
                    console.log("User: "+doc.data().uid)
                    return messaging.sendToDevice(deviceToken,payload) 
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            }));
        }); 
    }
    return Promise.all(allPromises);
});
```

**EDIT:**
I added a check to see if the deviceToken is present on the userData before sending the notification.

Comment: Hey Lunke thank you so much for your answer, I will test it right away

Comment: Since I have more than 500 orders in that collection, I think that I need to do this as a batch operation, can you help me updating this code to run on batchs of 500 operations ? or that batches are just used in write operations ? thanks

Comment: Batches are only used for set, update and delete operations for Cloud Firestore. See [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) to learn more about batches.